# FluentValidation message for nested properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, fluentvalidation

I have a class with a complex property:

```
public class A
{
    public B Prop { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I've added a validator:

```
public class AValidator : AbstractValidator<A>
{
    public AValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.A.Id)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Please ensure you have selected the A object");            
    }
}
```

But during client-side validation for `A.Id` I still have a default validation message: `'Id' must not be empty`. How can I change it to my string from the validator?

Comment: This appears to be [not supported](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/110). Suggested alternative approach is to have flat view models and avoid nesting of objects

Comment: This is supported, and depends on where you want to use your validators. Checkout my answer below.

Answer (score 27):

You can achieve this by using custom validator for nested object:

```
public class AValidator : AbstractValidator<A>
{
    public AValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.B).NotNull().SetValidator(new BValidator());
    }

    class BValidator : AbstractValidator<B>
    {
        public BValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please ensure you have selected the B object");
        }
    }
}

public class A
{
    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

There is an alternative option here. When configuring FluentValidation in your `Startup` class you can set the following `configuration.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;`

So the full code might look something like this

```cs
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddFluentValidation(configuration =>
        {
            ...
            configuration.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
            ...
        })
```

So you would still have two validators one for class `A` and one for class `B`, then class `B` would be validated.

The documentation states:

> Whether or not child properties should be implicitly validated if a matching validator can be found. By default this is false, and you should wire up child validators using SetValidator.

So setting this to `true` implies that child properties will be validated.

Comment: That's very interesting , would you happen to know how one would unit test this?

Comment: I would be interested how it can be incorporate with rulesets. How you can define the valid validation ruleset when your nested object will be validated?

Comment: this solution is now deprecated, see https://github.com/fluentvalidation/fluentvalidation/issues/1960 for more information. The solution now is to call `SetValidator` instead, see https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/start.html#complex-properties

Answer (score 7):

Pretty old question but for future generations - you can either use a child validator or define child rules inline as described in the official documentation: https://fluentvalidation.net/start#complex-properties

Answer (score 3):

**It depends on where you want to use your validators:**

In the common scenario, where we have an application with N layers,
in the ASP.net layer, for the validation of `View Models`, `DTOs` or `Commands` (e.g. to achieve fail-fast validation), just enable  `ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties`, as @StevenYates said:

```csharp
services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv => 
{
    fv.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
});
```

When this is enabled, instead of having to specify child validators using `SetValidator`, MVC’s validation infrastructure will recursively attempt to automatically find validators for each property automatically.

IMHO, this is great, because besides being practical, it prevents us from forgetting some `.SetValidator (...)`!

> Note that if you enable this behaviour you should not use SetValidator
> for child properties, or the validator will be executed twice.

Doc: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#implicit-vs-explicit-child-property-validation

---

But, in addition (or instead) of that, if you want to use FluentValidation in other layers (e.g. Domain), you need to use the `SetValidator(...)` method, as @t138 said, for example:

```csharp
RuleFor(customer => customer.Address).SetValidator(new AddressValidator());
```

Doc: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/start.html#complex-properties

Answer (score 2):

You can use ChildRules method:

```
public class AValidator : AbstractValidator<A>
{
    public AValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Prop)
            .ChildRules(x => x.RuleFor(b => b.Id))
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Please ensure you have selected the A object");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A
{
    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class AValidator : AbstractValidator<A>
{
    public AValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.B).NotNull().SetValidator(new BValidator());
    }

    class BValidator : AbstractValidator<B>
    {
        public BValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotEmpty().WithMessage("message ....");

        }
    }
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
          
            services.AddControllers().AddFluentValidation(fv =>
            {
                fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();
                fv.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
            });
    }
```